# jquery selector with exception

Tags: jquery, selector

I have a table like div construct with 4 "columns" in each row:

```
<div class="entry-row">
    <div class="entry-color">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="entry-item">aaa</div>
    <div class="entry-buttons">xxx</div> 
    <div class="entry-count">bbb</div>
</div>
```

with css:

```
.entry-row
{
  width:100%;
  display: table-row;
  height:32px;
}
.entry-color
{
    float:left;
    margin-right: 3px;
    display:table-cell;
    height:32px;
}
.entry-item
{
    float:left;
    height:32px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display:table-cell;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 120%;
}
.entry-count
{
    float:right;
    height:32px;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right:3px;
}
.entry-buttons
{
    float:right;
    height:32px;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

so it looks like: |aaa _____________ bbb _ xxx|

I want to use a click event on the whole row except the buttonpart (xxx)

I used a click handler on the row with not for the buttons:

```
$(".entry-row").not(".entry-buttons").click(function() {
    alert("1");
});
```

but it is executed on the buttons as well. 
I think I cant use a selector for entry-item and entry-count because there can be a gap between them if the content is to short.

How can I get a click handler for the whole row but not on the button div?

Comment: Just wondering but if you want rows, why don't you use a `table`?

Comment: the columns can have different width in each row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `event.stopPropagation()`.

You can see my fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/ebilgin/rL0bmucw/

Answer (score 0):

Just add an if clause to prevent the click on this function

```js
$(".entry-row").click(function(e) {
    if(e.target.className!=='entry-buttons'){
      alert(1);
    }else{
      //if you want to execute anything on .entry-buttons else leave it blank or discard the else
    }
});
```

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding of question. 'entry-buttons' inside of an 'entry-row'.